# Javascript array: how to group

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

I have unsorted array with some data and I want to create new array width sorted data:

```
   var gridData = [], i = -1;
        while (i++ < 5) {
                gridData[i] = {
                    "ProjectOwner": ["Corporation1","Corporation2","Corporation3"][i % 2],
                    "ProjectId": i,
                    "ProjectName": String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i % 3) + (1 + i % 3),
                    "ProjectType": ["Conference","Programming","Research","Conference"][i % 4],
                    "ProjectLeader": "Name1Name2Name3".substr(i % 3 * 5,5) + " " + "Surname1Surname2Surname3".substr(i % 3 * 8,8),
                    "StartDate": new Date(2009 + i % 4 % 2, (i + 3) % 12, 5 + i * 4 % 24).toLocaleDateString(),
                    "EndDate": new Date(2010 + i % 4 % 2, (i + 3) % 12, 5 + i * 4 % 24).toLocaleDateString(),
                    "Summary": "bla bla"
                };
            }
```

unsorted data looks like object array

and I would like to group it like

```
//First group by ProjectOwner
Object {Corporation1: Array[3], Corporation2: Array[3]}
   //Second group by ProjectName
   Corporation1: Array[x]
            A1 : Array [x]
                 Object1
                 Object2
                 ...
   Corporation2: Array[x]
```

and so on...
I have tried array.map and reduce but they don't seem to work in IE
   also I have tried:

```
$.each(aggregation_content, function(i,aggr) {

    $.each(_newData, function(a, objA) {
        if(i > 0)
            o = _newData[a][aggregation_content[i - 1].cell];
        n = _newData[a][aggregation_content[i].cell];

        if(typeof o == "undefined") //For first row when new Data is empty array
        {
            if(! (n in newData))
                newData[n] = [];
            newData[n].push(objA);
        }
    })})
console.log(newData);
```

where aggregation_content is

```
{cell:"ProjectOwner",value:""},{cell:"ProjectName",value:""},{cell:"ProjectLeader",value:""},{cell:"ProjectType",value:""}
```

and new data is a gridData from the beginning.
this works perfectly for a first aggregation. but the problem is that when I aggregate the array newData I need to use

```
if(! (n in newData[o]))
    newData[o][n] = [];
 newData[o][n].push(objA);
```

and that [o] should be a parent of [n] -node.
ok- second group is ok too with that code, but when I want to make 5 inner groups I need to do it like

```
newData["firstGroup"]["secondGroup"]["thirdGroup"]...[n].push("Some content").
```

How can this be made programmatically? If I do

```
newData = newData[o] - no good
or
temp = newData
do something to temp
newData[o] = temp not good eather :'(
```

I hope I wrote understandable text  :D

____Edited_2012_12_13______________________________________

So the input data is

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
  0: Object
   EndDate: "Monday, April 05, 2010"
   ProjectId: 0
   ProjectLeader: "Name1 Surname1"
   ProjectName: "A1"
   ProjectOwner: "Corporation1"
   ProjectType: "Conference"
   StartDate: "Sunday, April 05, 2009"
   Summary: "bla bla"
   __proto__: Object
 1: Object
   EndDate: "Monday, May 09, 2011"
   ProjectId: 1
   ProjectLeader: "Name2 Surname2"
   ProjectName: "B2"
   ProjectOwner: "Corporation2"
   ProjectType: "Programming"
   StartDate: "Sunday, May 09, 2010"
   Summary: "bla bla"
   __proto__: Object
 2: Object
   ...
 3: Object
    ...
 4: Object
    ...
 5: Object
    ....
```

And the output data should be something like

```
Object {Corporation1: Array[3], Corporation2: Array[3]}
 Corporation1: Array[2]
   0: A1:  Array[X]
         0: Object
            EndDate: "Monday, May 09, 2011"
            ProjectId: 1
            ProjectLeader: "Name2 Surname2"
            ProjectName: "A1"
            ProjectOwner: "Corporation2"
            ProjectType: "Programming"
            StartDate: "Sunday, May 09, 2010"
            Summary: "bla bla"
         1: Object
            ...
            ...
   1: B2:  Array[X]
         0: Object
            EndDate: "Monday, May 09, 2011"
            ProjectId: 1
            ProjectLeader: "Name2 Surname2"
            ProjectName: "B2"
            ProjectOwner: "Corporation2"
            ProjectType: "Programming"
            StartDate: "Sunday, May 09, 2010"
            Summary: "bla bla"
         1: Object
            ...
            ...
 Corporation2: Array[2]
   0: A1:  Array[X]
         0: Object
            EndDate: "Monday, May 09, 2011"
            ProjectId: 1
            ProjectLeader: "Name2 Surname2"
            ProjectName: "A1"
            ProjectOwner: "Corporation2"
            ProjectType: "Programming"
            StartDate: "Sunday, May 09, 2010"
            Summary: "bla bla"
         1: Object
            ...
            ...
   1: B2:  Array[X]
         0: Object
            EndDate: "Monday, May 09, 2011"
            ProjectId: 1
            ProjectLeader: "Name2 Surname2"
            ProjectName: "B2"
            ProjectOwner: "Corporation2"
            ProjectType: "Programming"
            StartDate: "Sunday, May 09, 2010"
            Summary: "bla bla"
         1: Object
            ...
            ...
```

The tree view should be two or more nested nodes.

Comment: Can you please just post boiled down what you tried and what you are trying to do in one fell swoop? (and maybe with a fiddle example of what is going wrong?)

Comment: ill post raw data tomorrow, cause am out of my working place for now. thank you for a fast reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this resoult:

```
this.groupBy = function(originalData, aggregation_content) 
    {
        var parentNode,node,i,j,g;
        var newData = {},temp;
        this.array.sortedData = originalData;
        $.each(aggregation_content,function(i,objI){
            $.each(originalData.Items,function(j,objJ){
                node = originalData.Items[j].GetValue(aggregation_content[i].column).replace(/\W+/gi,"");
                if(i > 0)
                {
                    temp = newData;
                    $.each(aggregation_content,function(g,objG){
                        parentNode = originalData.Items[j].GetValue(aggregation_content[g].column).replace(/\W+/gi,"");
                        if(!temp[parentNode])
                        {   
                            temp[parentNode] = [];
                        }
                        temp = temp[parentNode];
                    });
                    temp.push(objJ);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!newData[node])
                        newData[node] = [];
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(newData);
        return newData;           
    }
```

what i do is i make new treeview (multidimencional) array filled with pointers.
so the output is grouped by aggregation_content.

Answer (score 1):

I have suffered similar situation earlier. I wrote a library to do this:

https://github.com/raghavv/array-mod

Please check it. I am not promoting my library but I think it fits your requirement.

Also, for older browser support IE < 9. You will also need to include another excellent library:

https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/

Here is how you get your first set of arrays:

> a$(gridData).findAll("Corporation1", "ProjectOwner");
>   a$(gridData).findAll("Corporation2", "ProjectOwner");
>   a$(gridData).findAll("A1", "ProjectName");
>   a$(gridData).findAll("B2", "ProjectName");

Comment: Thank you for a response. ill dig into it tomorrow, all data is on working pc. ill let u know if i found something.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop counter to group into sets based on length:

```
var foo = [57657,57751,58401,58420,58588,58655,59238,59443,59488,59492,59570,59706,59924,59925, 57674, 57687, 57688, 57689, 57693, 57770, 57785, 57786, 57796, 57798, 57810, 57827, 57829, 57835, 57850, 57851, 57852, 57903, 57909, 57910,57957, 57972, 57998, 58022, 58046, 58059, 58064, 58077, 58085, 58097, 58103, 58105, 58127, 58138, 58139, 58220, 58320, 58353, 58356, 58357,58358, 58359, 58360, 58402, 58403, 58404, 58467, 58472, 58473, 58493, 58605]


/* Group into sets of twenty */
var i = 0; while (i <= foo.length) { Math[i] = foo.slice(i, i+20).toString(); i = i + 20; }
```